# Get the name of a custom attribute from attrs.xml

Tags: android, xml

I have created custom attributes in `attrs.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="StarWars">
  <attr name="sw_jedi" format="string" />
  <attr name="sw_rank" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I get the int value backed in `R` (for example `R.styleable.StarWars_sw_jedi`) but how can I get the attribute `name` (`jedi`) ?

EDIT to be more specific :

I want the "name" String of the attribute not the value from R (which is an int) :

For example, I want to retrieve "jedi" and not the int (`R.styleable.StarWars_sw_jedi` or `R.attr.sw_jedi`)

In fact i would like a `getAttributeName(R.styleable.StarWars_sw_jedi)`

Thx in advance !

Comment: R.attr.jedi doesn't work?

Comment: You are calling it in a correct way....clean the project once..

Comment: I don't want to get the int but the name String, I edited the OP to be more specific, It was misundersting sorry

Comment: Oki I found it, I guess I was too tired yesterday :s The function I was looking for is getResourceEntryName()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know why I didn't find it but the function I was looking for is [getResourceEntryName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29) which actually does exactly what I want

In my case if I want "jedi" I will do :

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.attr.sw_jedi);
```

Comment: Np Pragnani, I did one here too by not finding this function :) I upvote you for the time you spend here, have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

I have Worked on your same Style and is working perfectly check once for reference.

step 1:

Create custom style by creating a file attrs.xml in res/values folder

here is attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="StarWars">
  <attr name="sw_jedi" format="string" />
  <attr name="sw_rank" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Declare the format you have specified in `res/values/strings.xml`

```
   <string name="sw_jedi">Hi</string>
        <string name="sw_rank">Bye</string>
```

And when I use in my java code

it works without any ambiguity.

If you want to get the value of jedi do like this

```
 String jedi=getResources().getResourceEntryName(StarWars_sw_jedi);
```

Comment: Yep I know that, I just was looking for getResourceEntryName() function : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName(int) I was too tired I guess :s

Comment: Your edited code won't work, R.styleable.StarWars_sw_jedi return the position of the sw_jedi in StarWars (which is int[]) so 0, see my answer above